# incorrect syntax near ',' ..

Tags: sql

I am having an error executing this query.

```
Delete from customerpayment where customerid = 8, Paymentid = 1 , currentpayment = '132', startdate = '1/1/2011', enddate = '12/31/2011', status = 'Paid';
```

Comment: Maybe you have a look at your other questions first, you have so far accepted no answer at all. Other that that, have you actually gone through the trouble of looking at other SQL statements and comparing them to yours? The difference should be pretty obvious.

Comment: ok ok ok!!! i got u!! :) thanks mate! i dindt knew that :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `and` instead of `,` and your query should work.

More precisely:

```
delete from customerpayment where customerid = 8 and Paymentid = 1 and currentpayment = '132' and startdate = '1/1/2011' and enddate = '12/31/2011' and status = 'Paid';
```

A few suggestions: it seems you're using `string` data structure for representing dates. This is bad practise and you should use your database's internal date structure for things like this.

If `currentpayment` is always a number, don't use `string`.

If you have only few possible `status` values, rather use a different table with all possible status values and then join it based on id.

Comment: @Abid: `'132'` is a string, `132` is a numeric value.

Comment: but there is a textbox in the form in which the value of the current payment resides.. so due to the concern that all the values in the textbox are a string, i have written '132' in quotes..

Comment: @Abid: then it's possible a value like `hello1234` will end up in your database. What you're doing is bad practise since you should check on server side if current payment is indeed a number. If it is, only then you should insert it into your database.

Comment: @darioo, what i just commented was my concept.. if i am mistaken, please correct me .. regards mate!

Comment: @Abid: be a fair player and accept other's good answers. Things I've told you can help you in your design. Rule of thumb: you should always check on server side input from your users before allowing it to get into your database.

Comment: I dont have any problem to be a fair player but my friend i did not knew how to rate the answers.. u just told me that.. and i will now rate all the good and knowledgeable comments..